# De-Auth "attacks" using Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-micro

I'm trying to use my Arduino and an ESP8266 to spam De-Auth "attacks". I am quoting attacks because I do not plan on using this for malicious or destructive purposes. I've heard that the ESP8266 supports monitor mode, but I haven't found any information about using it to spam De-Auth packets. I want to do something similar to the mdk3 command in Linux (mdk3  d).

If you need me to clarify anything, please just ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you'll need version 2.0.0 (or earlier?) version of the arduino esp8266 stuff if  you want to compile something that can do this

Comment: This seems to be a question about the ESP8266 and not about an Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

If you can transmit raw 802.11, take a look at the code for aircrack-ng, specifically aireplay-ng.c - this software is known to work on arm boards.

Answer (score 0):

Check this GitHub repo, could be what you are looking for: https://github.com/spacehuhn/esp8266_deauther